# How to mark gmail UNREAD emails using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail, inbox

I am using tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188349/Read-Gmail-Inbox-Message-in-ASP-NET to make a gmail client. Using the code in this tutorial I am retrieving all emails from INBOX. I have a problem with distinguishing the UNREAD ones. Can you help me with that one, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're communicating using POP3, there isn't a way to tell what is unread.  You will need to talk over some other API (perhaps Gmail Inbox Feed?)

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/#gmail_inbox_feed